# How to get wcf communiction ONLY over Https

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, https, wsdl

I want to have a WCF service with all requests being autenticated, authorised and send only over the https.
I generated a certificate for SLL. For development I'm using ISS Express.
Also in web.config I turn any http option to false. But still in generated WSDL and when I'm using WCFStorm for checking the service methods it still uses `http://localhost:1947` instead of `https://localhost:44300` I declared. What I need to change to be sure that all communication will go over the https?
Here is my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="AF.Services.AFService" behaviorConfiguration="AFServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="AFService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="AF.Common.Services.IAFService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AFServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="AFCert"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My" />
            <userNameAuthentication
                userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="AF.Services.UserValidator, AF.Services" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- TODO zmienić przed deployem!!-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

The web page describing how to use the service is accesible only through the 44300 https port.

Comment: You need `<securityMode="TransportWithMessageCredential">`, I believe, to force only SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [How to: Use Transport Security and Message Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the Using Configuration section, it appears that you need the following security settings in your binding configuration:

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
</security>
```

So your complete binding configuration would look like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="secureBinding">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Also note that you don't actually assign your defined binding to your endpoint, so currently you're getting the default values for `wsHttpBinding` (the default for security mode is "Message").  You can assign the binding configuration above through the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the `endpoint` element:

```
<services>
  <service name="AF.Services.AFService" behaviorConfiguration="AFServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="AFService.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureBinding"
              contract="AF.Common.Services.IAFService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add bindingConfiguration. Sometimes You just need the second pair of eyes. Also added `TransportWithMessageCredential` mode like You said. Works perfectly!